# Any other configuration is needed for scheduler to work for Jbosss 7.1.1?

Tags: java, jboss

I want to run a scheduler for every minute. So I have the below code to perform that. In server console I can see the bean registration but it doesn't trigger at all. Need help.

> ```
> @Startup
> @Singleton
> public class AutomaticSchedulerBean {
>
>   @Schedule(year = "*", dayOfWeek = "*", hour = "*", minute = "*", persistent = false)
>   public void backgroundProcessing() {
>             //perform task here
>
>       }
>   }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that should be all you need.  Works for me on JBoss EAP 6.1...I'm unable to try it on 7.1.1.  Can you post your whole class? Specifically imports.

**Edit**
Scratch that, I have tried that on a default 7.1.1 install and it works for me.  The only thing I can think is you're using javax.inject.Singleton rather than javax.ejb.Singleton but then I wouldn't expect to see the bean registered on deployment.  Confirm your imports and if you're still unable to get it working try just deploying the single bean in an ejb jar to take everything else out of the picture.